# Magento Api Error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.7

When I run following code in magento root

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/mymagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$session = $client->login('testuser', 'testuser');              
    $result = $client->salesOrderList($session);                    
echo"<pre>";
    print_r($result);
echo"</pre>";
?>
```

I am getting following error

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable. in /var/www/html/mymagento/sales_order.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mymagento/sales_order.php(9): SoapClient->__call('salesOrderList', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/mymagento/sales_order.php(9): SoapClient->salesOrderList('98850601ed8aa6f...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/mymagento/sales_order.php on line 9
```

But when I run

```
$result = $client->salesOrderInfo($session,'100000030');
```

No error comes.

How to fix this?
Please help

Comment: Look on permissions on API account and on hard drive files rights.

Comment: @Martin I have created a user in admin as testuser and assigned this resources sales and catalog. Can you please explain meaning of permissions on API account?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean. Also check permissions on all the files in Magento folder (but this will be not a solution i think).

Comment: @Martin can this problem be because I am overriding  public function info($orderIncrementId) of  Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2 class

Comment: this in my case was related to the wrong path for model given in api.xml (i was giving the path to file rather it requires a path to directory i.e, mymodel/mymodel not the mymodel/mymodel_file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you are trying to access a resource which is not available where it should be.Like the class file.

In my project I got this error, one directory was not at proper location.Please check you directory structure which you are creating for the overriding the core files. Or check if the core files directory structure has been disturbed mistakenly.

Comment: To see a good directory structure http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-api-v2/ ; in my case, I had a typo in my API class name

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using `localhost` use IP address of your local system. Default IP address is 127.0.0.1.

So, your code should me like this:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/mymagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$session = $client->login('testuser', 'testuser');              
$result = $client->salesOrderList($session);                    
echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo"</pre>";
?>
```

Try this, hope will help!

Comment: Do you think I am not passing any filter value this may be the reason for the problem?

Comment: No, use IP address in stead of 'localhost' in first line that is SOAP URL `http://127.0.0.1/mymagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1`

Comment: I tried the same thing on my development server other than my loaclhost, I am getting same error. Actually what is meaning of "Resource path is not callable"

Comment: open `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc\wsdl.xml` and find `salesOrderList` operation and posttype is exits or not.

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by "posttype is exits or not"

Comment: these code should be there `<portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="salesOrderList">
            <documentation>Retrieve list of orders by filters</documentation>
            <input message="typens:salesOrderListRequest" />
            <output message="typens:salesOrderListResponse" />
        </operation></portType>`